# ExtJS AOP similar to that provided in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, extjs, aop

I have used this [dojo plugin](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/may/18/aop-aspect-javascript-dojo/) that provides a wonderful implementation of declarative AOP.  Does anybody know of a similar plugin/library for ExtJS or for vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext adds a couple of basic AOP-related functions to the [Function prototype](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Function) (createInterceptor and createSequence).  I would not call it a full-fledged AOP implementation by any means, but they are helpful in many cases.  I'm not familiar with any Ext plugins or standalone JS implementations of AOP.

Comment: ExtJS is quick to tout the usefulness of those functions (and I agree), but I am hoping to find a declarative AOP package.  There are many things about dojo I dislike - a relationship cultivated through months of use - but "their" AOP plugin is sweet!  thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen anything like that for Ext.  I don't use Dojo, so I don't know how much code there is in their AOP stuff, but maybe you could port their plugin to Ext if it's that important.